# How to use length of wire as "buttons"

Tags: arduino

I apologize if this is a super beginner question, but Im a beginner so thats probably why.

Ive built a program on arduino that takes the readout from a potentiometer, and"maps" it to three buttons.

Ie.   when readout is 40-50 (button1), when readout is 350-500 (button2), when readout is 800-1023 (button3)

Now I want to actually apply it to what its actually going to be used for in the real world.  Which requires the potentiometer to become just a "length of wire".

Depending on where I touch it, I will convert the readout into corresponding button presses.

How can I do this?  Like how do I make just a length of wire, act like a sort of "fader".

I assume this is how some "keybeds" in keyboards work.  With the rail? Im looking for an example of how to hook such a system up.

Comment: What you want is called capacitive sensing.

Comment: How long is the wire? And could other materials besides a single metallic wire be used?

Comment: @Passerby Perhaps. How would capacitive sensing be implemented along a wire?

Comment: Im essentially wanting to replicate the idea used on Perregrine gaming Gloves. Where the thumb is an electrode, and the fingers are a wire that allow for different areas to register different "touch areas".   Google it to see what I mean.  Im assuming each area on the finger registers a different voltage/number, that the arduino will be able to decode as an "area/button".

Comment: That can be done with cap sensing, or with a resistor ladder.

Comment: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8681 check if this can help you, it's a "softpot", a linear potentiometer driven by the position you press on the membrane

Answer (score 1):

As you might know, a "wire pot" has **three** terminals.  It has two ends, plus a "slider."
If you place a copper bead on the wire and tie the ends of the wire to some insulator, you will now have a **"linear"** potentiometer.

Solder a wire to **each end** and the **copper bead**. Connect the wires to the corresponding terminals on the PCB, and you are "good to go."

If you really meant "use your finger" as the slider, then you need a different (and more complex) circuit.  I would recommend using an "oscillator" and your hand would serve as the tuning capacitance.